# What piece of software governs/owns 'registerDomMutation'?

Tags: javascript, sentry, mutation-observers

Recently, in a piece of software I'm working on, I have been receiving a spate of errors in Sentry from clients that I'm having a lot of trouble pinning down. The specific error is this:

```
Non-Error promise rejection captured with value: 'registerDomMutation' is not defined
```

The specific error seems to be generated by Sentry itself as it attempts to capture some other problem. What has really got me stuck is that I can't track down where `registerDomMutation` is being called, or which piece of software that should be defining it. It doesn't appear to be part of Sentry; I know that it's not in my code; and it doesn't appear to be in any of the packages I use. It sounds like it could be a browser method of some kind, but I can't find any information on it. This error only seems to be occurring in the new version of iOS Safari (14.3), but it's also not occurring consistently.

Is anyone familiar with this method? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's definitely [not a browser method](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=registerDomMutation).

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this issue?

Comment: No, never. Are you seeing this as well?

Comment: Since wOxxOm proved it's not the browser, it must be sentry. You are a paying customer. Therefore you should contact their support. After all this is most likely a bug.

Comment: I have contacted them, but they have not copped to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they're coming from internal WebView of [Klarna](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id1115120118) application. I cannot seem to find any source code for the app to prove this point. But recurring `Klarna/<some version>` pattern shared among all the errors' userAgent string makes me think so.

Android version of the app is affected too. I guess they are sharing the same JS code.

I have strict CSP rules regarding scripts allowed to run on my page and I guess some code the app is relying on just doesn't run due to them.

Comment: interesting theory! This seems to affect clients that don't use Klarna, so I don't think it's that, unfortunately, but I'm going to dig further.